# Deppen Leer Zeichen

Tags: spelling, compound, hyphen

Für falsch geschriebene Substantivverbindungen wie *Holz Tisch* statt *Holztisch,* oder häufiger *Diät Apfel Saft* statt *Diätapfelsaft,* insbesondere im Bereich Marketing und Produktbezeichnungen zu finden, wird oft der Begriff *Deppenleerzeichen* verwendet.

Kennt jemand Beispiele, in denen ein derart falsch geschriebenes Wort im Kontext eines Satzes zu einer Mehrdeutigkeit führt?

Am liebsten wäre mir ein Satz, der dies ohne Kommafehler erreicht, aber zur Not sehe ich über solche hinweg (oft auch unabsichtlich, aber das gehört nicht hierher).

Ein schwaches Beipiel:

> Wir kaufen Katzen Futter.
>   Wir kaufen Katzenfutter.

Letztlich entsteht hier kaum ein großes Missverständnis, wiewohl der erste Satz sich auf einen normalen Fischeinkauf beziehen könnte.

Comment: +1 für die Leerzeichen in der Überschrift.

Answer (score 25):

Ein bekanntes Beispiel ist auf folgendem Wegweiser zu finden:

[image: Uni Halle Uni-Halle]

Gemeint ist hier nicht etwa die Universität in Halle, sondern die Uni-Halle in Wuppertal.

--

*Update:*

Ein Versuch, einen Satz zu konstruieren:

> Ich mag Torten(,) Diagramme nicht.
>   Ich mag Tortendiagramme nicht.

oder vielleicht etwas origineller:

> Sie hatten den Personen Verkehr verboten.
>   Sie hatten den Personenverkehr verboten.

Comment: Gefragt waren zwar Sätze, aber das Beispiel ist zu schön, und einen Satz zu bilden trivial. Ich würde sogar zu Unihalle tendieren.

Comment: @user okay, mal etwas nachgedacht und zwei Sätze zusammengebastelt.

Comment: Oh, die gefallen mir beide sehr gut! Das ist wohl nur durch Konstruktionen mit mehr als einem Leerzeichen zu toppen. Am Ende machen wir einen Eintopf der Art: "In der Uni Halle hatten sie den Personen Verkehr verboten". :)

Answer (score 21):

In [diesem Zwiebelfisch-Artikel](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,333774,00.html) gibt es zwei nette Beispiele für Mehrdeutigkeiten, die durch Einsatz des Deppenleerzeichens entstehen:

[image: Grundlose Gebühren?]

[image: Wahnsinnige Windmühlen?]

Comment: Sehr schön finde ich auch "Diebstahl gesichert" im Fenster eines zum Verkauf angebotenen Autos (wo ich das gesehen habe, weiß ich nicht mehr, könnte auch aus dem Zwiebelfisch sein). Das ideale Angebot für Versicherungsbetrüger! :-)

Comment: Wunderbar, auch wenn mein Lachen darüber beinahe meine frische Operationsnaht hätte aufplatzen lassen!

Comment: Gute Besserung, Ludi! :-)

Answer (score 9):

Aus der Zeit, in der in Italien noch [ziemlich große Zahlen auf den Geldscheinen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italienische_Lira#Republik) standen, könnte folgende Zeitungsmeldung (mit Deppenleerzeichen) stammen:

> Die italienische Polizei stellte bei den Geldfälschern einhundert fünfzig tausend Lira Scheine sicher.

Das könnten 5 Mill. Lire gewesen sein oder auch nur 150000. Oder irgendein anderer Betrag, verteilt auf 150000 Banknoten unbekannten und vielleicht sogar unterschiedlichen Nennwerts.

Ein Autobesitzer, der gerne auch mal sein Zweirad mitnimmt und sich angewöhnt hat, das entsprechende Zubehör als "Fahrrad Träger" zu Papier zu bringen, könnte eines Tages folgende Anzeige veröffentlichen:

> Verkaufe VW Golf mit Fahrrad und Ski-Träger.

Über Rückfragen, was für ein Fahrrad er denn da genau verkaufen wolle, sollte er sich dann nicht wundern.

Ganz analog funktioniert der Satz

> Essen Sie lieber Sahne- als Magerjoghurt.

der seine Bedeutung ändert, wenn man von "Sahne Joghurt" ausgeht und folglich den Bindestrich wegläßt.

Die Idee zu diesem Beispiel bekam ich durch eine [real existierende Veröffentlichung](https://deppenleerzeichen.de/2013/11/30/laptop-als-dreingabe/), die ich auf der Seite [deppenleerzeichen.de](https://deppenleerzeichen.de) fand. Eigentlich merkwürdig, dass niemand zuvor diese Fundgrube für Deppenleerzeichen aus der traurigen Wirklichkeit genannt hat. Einige der Einträge dort taugen auch als Antworten auf diese Frage oder können solche zumindest inspirieren:

[Auf einer Pressekonferenz stellte Porsche gestern seine neuen 911 Modelle vor.](https://deppenleerzeichen.de/2008/11/10/911-neue-modelle-bei-porsche/)

[Werden Sie auch zum Pudding Verführer und klicken Sie hier!](https://deppenleerzeichen.de/2007/06/13/zum-pudding-werden/) (Während man sich dick löffelt, kann man dann darüber rätseln, ob in diesem Satz zwei Kommas oder ein Bindestrich fehlen.)

["Deutschland Achter"](https://deppenleerzeichen.de/2006/10/30/deutschland-achter/) - mehr Worte braucht man nicht, um Deutschlands Renommee in der Sportwelt auf den Punkt zu bringen.

["Wir möchten Wolfs Spuren verfolgen."](https://deppenleerzeichen.de/2006/07/03/uni-hannover-alle-einwande-und-bedenken-sind-geklart/) schreiben ein paar Schulkinder in ihren Projektantrag, und der Lehrer rätselt, ob die Schüler damit zoologisches Interesse bekunden oder eher [biographisches](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_%28Familienname%29).

[Peugeot erwartet, dass sich ein Viertel aller 407 Diesel-Käufer für den neuen Motor entscheiden.](https://deppenleerzeichen.de/2006/06/25/nur-407-diesel-bei-peugeot-verkauft/)

[Der sogenannte Erzherzog Joseph Diamant wird in Genf unter den Hammer kommen.](https://deppenleerzeichen.de/2012/10/08/erzherzog-im-sonderangebot/)

A propos Schweiz: wer sich dort ein wenig auskennt, wird aus dem Satz "Zum Abschluß unserer Reise besichtigten wir die Wagner Kapelle." womöglich auf eine Tour durch den [Kanton St. Gallen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagen_SG) schließen. Doch dabei hat er die Rechnung ohne den Leerzeichen-Depp in der Lokalredaktion gemacht, der eigentlich über einen Besuch in [Niederbayern](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebrantshausen#Wagner-Kapelle) schreiben wollte.

Comment: Herrlich, der *Pudding Verführer* :-)

Comment: Hier einige meiner Favoriten von deppenleerzeichen.de:
• https://deppenleerzeichen.de/2017/10/05/nikon-general-ueberholt/
• https://deppenleerzeichen.de/2017/05/11/einen-berg-linsen-bitte/
• https://deppenleerzeichen.de/2013/02/23/mich-trifft-der-schlag/
• https://deppenleerzeichen.de/2017/01/29/das-behinderte-wc/
• https://deppenleerzeichen.de/2015/05/25/und-das-gluten-so-endlich-frei/

Answer (score 6):

Zwar mit Zeilenumbrüchen statt Leerzeichen und nicht im Kontext eines Satzes, sondern erst durch die Deppenleerzeichen zu einem Satz geworden:

[image: MACHT MISSBRAUCH ENTGEGEN WIRKEN !]

Wenn man es genauso liest, wie es dort steht, wird es zu einer Aufforderung zum Missbrauch, der sich gegen Wirken richtet.

Comment: Da war ja gleich ein ganzer Wählerbund von Deppen am Werk: Den Namen dieser Vereinigung könnte man auch so lesen, als ginge es da um den Dreiklang von Individuum, Staat und Kommune. - Schon bei deppenleerzeichen.de eingereicht?

Comment: Sehr schön auch, wie "Bürgerbund, Bonn" geschrieben wird. :)