# How do we translate "eye candy" in a user interface design context?

Tags: single-word-request, english-to-german, technical-terminology

The term **"eye candy"** is increasingly used for optical/graphical design gimmicks intended to make the user experience on various desktops more attractive.

#### Examples:

> - *"Your iPhone application development should be with **eye candy design** so people will be attracted at your app at first sight and would like to use it again and again."* <sup>[Source](http://whattoinvestin.com.au/iphone-app-development-get-the-best-return-on-investment/)</sup>
> - *"gDesklets is an architecture for "desklets", which are tiny applets
>     sitting on your desktop in a symbiotic relationship of **eye candy** and
>     usefulness."* <sup>[Source](http://packages.debian.org/en/squeeze/gdesklets)</sup>
> - *"Rubberbanding makes for good **eye candy** and makes the Mac feel familiar to those coming from the iOS world, but some users are annoyed with it and will appreciate the ability to disable the scroll elasticity completely."* <sup>[Source](http://osxdaily.com/tag/mac-os-x-10-7/)</sup>

How would you translate this to German?

**Related additional question:**
In case we decide not to tranlate it but use it as an English loanword instead, how would we then write it to make it both, correct, and "searchable" by a search engine? I can offer several options:

> **"Eye-Candy", Eye-Candy, "Eyecandy",
>
>   Eyecandy, "Eye Candy", Eye Candy,
>
>   "eye candy", "eyecandy", ...**

Comment: Augenkrebs vielleicht? :)

Comment: @Takkat:  Your first example is written in terrible English!  (I have no problem with people writing bad English - I don't write perfect German - but it's just funny to see it listed there as an example of the use of an English word.)

Comment: @Takkat: No, I don't think so.  The other examples look fine to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a hard one. Maybe:

- Augenschmankerl (regional)
- Hingucker
- Augenschmaus (schmausen is informal for eating, like to banquet)

Comment: Warum dann nicht einfach "Blickfang" oder "Augenweide", was die wohl geläufigste Übersetzungen für "eye candy" sind?

Comment: Blickfang ist aber doch eher "eye-catching" oder nicht?

Comment: @Em1 Augenweide ist mir nicht eingefallen (Entschuldigung!) und Blickfang trifft es nicht richtig, siehe Antwort von Jules.

Comment: +1 for *"Hingucker"* only ;)

Comment: @Jules Joa... Stimmt wohl. Da hab ich nicht nachgedacht und einfach nur kopiert ^^

Comment: @Jules: Aber _Blickfang_ ist eventuell ehrlicher - das ist doch schließlich der Zweck von "eye candy", oder? Es trifft sicher nicht immer zu, aber manchmal sollte man Euphemismen nicht wortgetreu übersetzen.

Comment: @HendrikVogt Dennoch hat er nicht unrecht. Es ist ein kleiner aber feiner Unterschied zwischen Blickfang und Augenweide. Während eine Augenweide etwas schönes beschreibt, muss ein Blickfang nicht schön sein. Eine grüne hässliche Tasche in einem sonst schwarz-weißen Bild ist genau so ein Blickfang, wie der Porsche Carrera inmitten von 20 Ford Fiestas. In den Beispielen von Takkat geht es aber eindeutig darum, dass etwas 'schön anzusehen ist'.

Comment: @Em1: Ja, es ist in der Tat ein Unterschied, und ich habe Jules ja auch nicht widersprochen. Ich meine ja nur, dass manchmal "eye candy" gesagt wird, wenn es vor allem um den Blickfang geht.

Comment: how about: optischer Leckerbissen

Comment: @Emanuel: How about posting this as an answer? `:-)`

Comment: @Emanuel Nette Idee. Nicht zuletzt, da du damit die Bedeutung von "eye candy = Augen-Bonbon" perfekt triffst. PS: Ich will das auch als Antwort lesen.

Answer (score 9):

As a translation for *eye candy* I like Emanuel's suggestion *optischer Leckerbissen* very much (which isn't posted as an answer yet). *Blickfang* was suggested by Em1, and I think that this can also be used in many situation. While it's not a direct translation (meaning *eye-catcher* rather than *eye candy*), I think it's often more honest to use *Blickfang*. After all, this is the main purpose of *eye candy!*

Thus, if you're in an advertising context, *optischer Leckerbissen* is more suitable; in other cases consider if *Blickfang* is more to the point.

Concerning your additional question: the [Duden Sprachratgeber](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/schreibung-von-fremdwoertern-aus-dem-englischen) recommends to write either *Eyecandy* or *Eye-Candy* since the term is composed of two nouns. This is analogous to the German *Erdbeermarmelade* or *Erdbeer-Marmelade*. Here, a space would be considered a [Deppenleerzeichen](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2383).

Comment: +1 v.a. für Blickfang.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't translate it, but only in the context of UI design and when talking to people from the industry. The English loan word conveys the right connotation.

Nevertheless, you could use the verbs "*aufhübschen*" oder "*verschönern*" in active voice. Common translations, such as "*Augenweide*" oder "*Augenschmaus*" are probably too intense when used for describing UI design paradigms.

Alternatively:

> *das Produkt soll über eine hochwertige Optik verfügen*

or for example 2:

> *eine symbiotische Beziehung von optischer/graphischer Attraktivität und Benutzbarkeit*"

Comment: Da du im zweiten Absatz die Sprache gewechselt hast, habe ich den einleitenden Satz ins Deutsche übersetzt.

Comment: @Em1 Ups. Ist mir auch beim ersten edit nicht aufgefallen. Die schweren Schaeden der Umgebung :) Ich hab's mal komplett auf Englisch abgefasst, da OP auch auf Englisch gefragt hat.

Comment: Welche Nebenbedeutung hast Du denn ausgemacht?

Answer (score 5):

Da ich eigentlich nur auf die Ergänzung antworten will, füge ich zunächst noch eine weitere Übersetzung ein, nämlich die wortgetreue Übersetzung: *Augen-Bonbon* (Danke, Wikipedia).

Bzgl. der Ergänzung: Solange wir uns darauf einigen, dass "*eye candy*" ein Fremdwort und kein Lehnwort ist, schreibst du es genau so, wie es im Englischen geschrieben wird; vorzugsweise in Anführungszeichen. Wahlweise kann es bis zu einem gewissen Grad an die deutsche Rechtschreibung bereits angepasst werden und großgeschrieben werden. Sprich **Eye Candy**.

Jedoch ist bspw. [eye-catcher bereits in den Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Eyecatcher) übernommen worden und wird wahlweise *Eyecatcher* oder *Eye-Catcher* geschrieben. Und die deutsche Wikipedia listet auch schon [Eye Candy](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_Candy) (gibt hier neben der wortgetreuen Übersetzung auch das umstrittene Wort *Blickfang* als mögliche Übersetzung an).
Da *Eye-Catcher* im Englischen mit Bindestrich geschrieben wird (und sich daher die deutsche Schreibweise erschließen lässt), *Eye Candy* jedoch nicht, würde ich zu der Wikipedia-Variante greifen und dieses Wort getrennt und beide Teilwörter großschreiben. Sprich **Eye Candy**.

Folglich, egal ob du es als Fremd- oder Lehnwort betrachtest, das Ergebnis ist identisch.

Comment: Und warum keinen Bindestrich? Den braucht man doch sonst bei zusammengesetzten Lehnwörten immer, oder ist das halt mal so, mal so?

Comment: @Takkat Wahrscheinlich mal so, mal so. ;p Gib mir mal ein paar Beispiele. Mir fallen gerade nur andere Beispiele für getrennte Schreibweise ein: z.B. User Interface schreibst du auch getrennt und groß (aber nie Userinterface oder User-Interface), auch wenn du natürlich die dt. Übersetzung zusammen schreibst (Benutzerschnittstelle).

Comment: die sagen auch mal so, mal-so, oder auch malso und sogar Mal so: http://www.duden.de/sprachratgeber/schreibung-von-fremdwoertern-aus-dem-englischen

Comment: @Takkat und Em1: Bitte _mit_ Bindestrich! Der Duden-Ratgeber sagt's auch ganz klar: Es handelt sich um eine Verbindung aus zwei Substantiven, also wird entweder zusammengeschrieben oder ein Bindestrich gesetzt. (_Eye Candy_ ist so sinnvoll wie _Erdbeer Marmelade_!)

Comment: Aus meiner Sicht die beste Antwort: Das ist nämlich der Begriff, den ich in diesem Kontext am meisten lese. 
Wenn man Fremdworte grundsätzlich furchtbar findet, dann ist das natürlich ärgerlich, trotzdem wird die Verwendung des englischen Fremdwortes in diesem Kontext am effektivsten sein.

Comment: Wer sagt, das Anführungszeichen erlaubt sind, mehr noch, empfohlen?

Answer (score 1):

In manchen Fällen, wenn es sich um zusätzliches Beiwerk handelt würde ich das auch nicht deutsche, aber etablierte *Dekoration* verwenden, insbes. für die Beispiele 2 und 3.

Leicht ironisch *Girlande* oder, schon abfällig, *Gekröse*.

Eye-candy ist aber oft nicht etwas, dass zusätzlich beigefügt, sondern abweichend gestaltet ist. Eyecandies sind also attraktive Gestaltungselemente, oder attraktiv *gemeinte* Gestaltungselemente, *Gekröse*, Knöpfe die derart spiegeln, etwa, dass das dargestellte Symbol nicht mehr erkennbar ist.

Hendrik Vogts Blickfang unterstütze ich aber auch.

Answer (score 1):

The (German) company I work for makes realistic model vehicles, and uses the term "**ein echter Blickfang**".

Answer (score 0):

Interessanterweise hat noch niemand die *Augenweide* als Übersetzung vorgeschlagen.

Es ist zwar in der Hinsicht interessant, dass anstelle einer Süßigkeit ein Leckerbissen fürs Vieh steht, aber ich halte den Begriff für schön plastisch.