# Spelling noun–noun compound words

Tags: translation, english-to-german, noun, spelling, compound

I am translating my meatloaf recipe to German and am unsure about translating *the meatloaf mixture* from the sentence

> Transfer the meatloaf mixture into the loaf pan.

I have: *meatloaf* → *der Hackbraten* and *mixture* → *die Mischung*.

I am undecided between:

> 1. die Hackbratenmischung
> 2. die Hackbraten-Mischung
> 3. die Hackbraten Mischung
> 4. der Hackbraten Mischung

I have already gone through:

- [How to make German compund noun?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18655/how-to-make-german-compound-noun)
- [Hyphen for compound nouns: Mathe-Wettbewerb or Mathewettbewerb?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20581/hyphen-for-compound-nouns-mathe-wettbewerb-or-mathewettbewerb)
- [German Compound Words](http://german.about.com/od/nounsandcases/a/German-Compound-Words.htm)
- [The Hyphen](http://german.about.com/od/writinggerman/a/The-Hyphen.htm)

I want to go with forms 1 or 2, but I remember seeing forms 3 and 4 somewhere, can’t recall where. Which of the above noun–noun compound word construction(s) are wrong? Please provide the reasons why they are incorrect.

Comment: I’d probably say _Masse_ for _mixture_ here, so _Hackbratenmasse_ or _Hackbraten-Masse_.

Comment: I assume if you'd also found [this one](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/7464/1224), then you would have been able to solve it yourselves. It seems that in none of the previous question all combinations were considered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the composition rules: 1 and 2 are ok. Case 1 is the normal choice in general, but you would prefer 2 over 1 if it leads to better readability, e.g. in cases of an unusual, unexpected composition. I think you already know this, because you linked to [Hyphen for compound nouns: Mathe-Wettbewerb or Mathewettbewerb?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20581/hyphen-for-compound-nouns-mathe-wettbewerb-or-mathewettbewerb?lq=1), and the answers there explain it quite well.

Case 3 is a common mistake, sometimes called ["Deppenleerzeichen"](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2383/9091). You cannot use the space for word composition in German, although many people (presumably under the influence of the English language) do so.

Case 4 adds the wrong gender to the error in 3.

For the wording in that specific case: don't use *Hackbraten*, since this would refer to the meal you want to have in the end. As long as it was not yet cooked, you better use *Hackfleisch*. So it is *Hackfleischmischung* or even better (thanks @chirlu) *Hackfleischmasse*.

Comment: I found your answer helpful and satisfactory. Thanks for providing the Deppenleerzeichen link. I think I'll go with _die Hackfleischmasse_.